# Need help writing a method to calculate duration (time) for Model/Views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, methods, models

My Rails 4 app has an appointments table, which has the following attributes/columns:  "date" (datatype date), "starts_at" (datatype time), and "ends_at" (datatype time).  I do not have a "duration" column, but want to calculate the difference between "ends-at" and "starts-at" times. I want the duration so I can put a validation in the Appointment model to prevent users from making appointments for less than 30 minutes or for more than 2 hours. I used Google to research the issue, but didn't find anything particularly helpful for what I'm trying to do.  I'm learning Rails, and trying to pick up best practices.  I'm assuming the place to put the "duration" logic is in the model, as opposed to the views. Right now, I don't believe users will need to see duration data. I started writing a "duration" method for the model, but can't get the logic to work properly.  Here's what I've done so far:

```
protected

  def duration
    (self.ends_at - self.starts_at).to_i
  end
```

I call the method with:

```
validate :duration, numericality: {greater_than: 30, less_than: 120}
```

When I execute the code it doesn't generate any errors, but the validation does not appear to do anything.  Users are still able to make appointments for less than 30 minutes or for more than 2 hours. I need to prevent both scenarios from being stored in the DB.  I played around with some if and else statements in the method, but no success.

Questions:

1. What's wrong with my current code?
2. Is there a better way to approach the problem to accomplish my objective?
3. If I do decide later to present "duration" information to users via the views, how do I accomplish that via embedded Ruby code?

I appreciate any help and advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the approach I would probably take:

The comments to the right were added just to explain a little of what was going on.

```
validate :duration

private

def duration
  length = (ends_at - starts_at) / 60
  return if length.between?(30, 120) # bail out of validation if length falls between the two integers

 errors.add(:base, 'Your error message') # you can change this to something like `:ends_at` if it's preferable..
end
```

More information on [comparables in Ruby](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Comparable.html#method-i-between-3F)

If you want to present the duration later on, I would most likely go the route of using a [presenter](http://nithinbekal.com/posts/rails-presenters/). But you could also just create an instance method on that model.

```
# Public: get the duration of the appointment in minutes
#
def duration
  (ends_at - starts_at) / 60
end
```

if this is the case, then you can do a little refactoring to the valiation

```
validate :correct_duration

private

def correct_duration
  length = self.duration
  return if length.between?(30, 120) # bail out of validation if length falls between the two integers

 errors.add(:base, 'Your error message') # you can change this to something like `:ends_at` if it's preferable..
end
```

Hope this works for ya.

Comment: Thanks Justin!  I'll review the code at my earliest opportunity.  I'll follow up with you.

Comment: Justin - I tried the validate :duration code, but I didn't have any luck. The validation prevents all appointments from being saved, regardless of duration. It's as if it's ignoring the 30, 120 minutes parameters. Any ideas of what could be causing this?  Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Justin, the problem is solved!  Your addition of "/ 60" to get the duration in minutes did it. The validation now appropriately blocks appointments < 30 or > 120 minutes. Fantastic! Also, thanks for the information about "presenters in Rails.' Very helpful!

Comment: lol yea sorry I went back and realized it was returning the time in seconds, not minutes :) glad it's working for you now.